# flyway: forcing migrations even if a SQL statement failed

Tags: oracle, migration, flyway

I've created a flyway project for an application at work. As it turns out, one of the developers already executed some of the SQL statements on TEST before I had the flyway setup ready for testing.

My sql script has a few statements:

```
ALTER TABLE "TABLE1" MODIFY ("NAME" VARCHAR2(75 CHAR));
ALTER TABLE "TABLE2" DROP ("BOARD_ID");
ALTER TABLE "TABLE3" ADD CONSTRAINT "SYS_C0022270" CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL) ENABLE;
```

The column that should be dropped on statement #2, has already been dropped manually on our TEST instance. It hasn't been dropped on our PROD instance, and I'd like to do it via a migration rather than manually.

Obviously, I'm not running a migration on PROD without trying it out on TEST first (there's a lot more stuff than these three queries).

But since the migration I'm having problems with is the first in line, it can't continue.

Is there any way to force it through? I know that column has been removed already. I could create it again, and then have the migration remove it. But I may have other queries down the line that may fail (creating seed data that may exist already, etc). And I wouldn't want that to stop our deployments.

Any ideas other than cloning our DB from PROD again and having the dev team stop their development while I prepare a new set of migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it, **recreating the column** does really sound like **the best solution.**

It is super simple and if the only purpose is to let the column be dropped again immediately afterwards, absolutely harmless.

Unless I miss part of the story, I fail to understand how the future creation of seed data could conflict with this.

The long term solution is of course a change in dev culture and a complete ban on manual DB changes.

Comment: To give you an example of a seed data conflict: we have some objects that point to a jasper template that is stored on the database. More than one record points to that template. The SQL script for each object has a query to create the template in case it does not exist. (Because at the time of development it was unknown which object would be deployed first). After the first script runs, all others would fail because of a single query that we don't really care about, because it has already been inserted.

Comment: I know we should remove the query from each file, and make it an independent script. But a way to ignore failed queries would have worked also. Now, I'm not suggesting you implement such a feature because of our unique need. I was just wondering if there was something similar in place.

Comment: And what does this have to do with the dropped column? Or was this just one example among many?

Comment: OK, I understand. No, there is currently no such feature built into the framework. Some of the other answers might be good workarounds for your situation (even though they are solving symptoms instead of the root cause)

Comment: The dropped column failure was just one example of a failure that is not critical. In the same way that a record that failed to insert because it exists is also not something that we would want to halt the migration over.

Answer (score 5):

You can put any SQL statements you want to ignore errors for inside a PL/SQL block with an exception handler:

```
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE "TABLE1" MODIFY ("NAME" VARCHAR2(75 CHAR))';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- perhaps print a message about the command failure here
END;
/
```

DDL must be done inside an execute immediate statement within PL/SQL.

A bit painful, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! This does work. Only problem is flyway doesn't seem to return whatever "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()" returns. I'm gonna script something simple using sqlplus, and after our upcoming release re-clone our PROD db and start all over again.

Comment: You also could use utl_file to write your messages to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlplus to run your script then you can add following statement at the beginning:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE
```

Comment: That didn't work: `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`. I'm guessing that's a SQL*Plus only construct.

Answer (score 0):

WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE and 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() does'nt work with flyway it is SQLPLUS client specific, you could use RAISE

```
EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM || CHR(10) ||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);

ROLLBACK;

Raise_Application_Error (-20000, SQLERRM || ' : ' ||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);

END;
```

Flyway will stop the migration process and print in log the issue.

If you want to continue migration don't user raise but another print solution.
tested with flyway 4.0.3